# Is there a nice way to cover the loading of an apex:iFrame?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

We are using `iframe`s to load results from a search. I would like to know how to cover the loading of the contents in the `iframe` with a nice spinning icon. If the search results were being displayed in the same page, I would use an `ActionStatus` [component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionStatus.htm). Is there something similar that I can use with an iframe?

---

For example: using an `ActionStatus` component,

```
 <apex:actionStatus id="resultTableStatus">
 <apex:facet name="start">
        <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:image value="{!$Resource.loading_icon}" />
            <apex:outputText >{!$Label.search_task_label_searching}</apex:outputText>
        </apex:outputPanel>
     </apex:facet>
     <apex:facet name="stop">
         <!--contents-->
     </apex:facet>
 </apex:actionStatus>
```

---

Extra code example and explanation (as requested in comments):

```
<iframe id="frameID" onLoad="autoResize('frameID');"
                            src="/apex/PageName?p1={!p1Value}"
                            height="300px"
                            style="width: 100%; background-color: transparent;"
                            frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The search happens in the `Controller` of the `Page` that the iFrame encloses (in the example above, `PageName`'s `Controller`). When the controller's constructor is called, the search method gets run (using the parameters past in). The controller sets a `List` property that holds the results of the search. The `Page` then uses a `Repeat` component to loop over the result list and populate a table.

Comment: We really need to see the iframe code - is the search executed in the iframe, or does the URL of the iframe pull in a standard page or something else?

Comment: @BobBuzzard - added extra code and explanation as requested. Thanks.

Comment: How does the search get executed - page action attribute, javascript onload handler, in the constructor?

Comment: @BobBuzzard - in the constructor (added this and more details into the question) - thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make your search run asynchronously to show a spinner.

There's a few ways to do this, but one way would be to have some JavaScript execute an actionfunction that executes the search - then you can use the facets as you would on your main page.  Adding a function to the existing onload handler(s) would do it (there's an example of this on my blog at: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/onload-handling.html).

You can still pull the search term from the URL in the constructor, just move the actual search out to an action method.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to get the extra information and posting an answer. I will have to try the answer tomorrow, but for now +1.